# Adobe Acrobat Form Connecting to Database

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am trying to connect to a local database on my computer and eventually connect to a hosted database on a shared drive. I have read the documentation for JavaScript for Adobe Acrobat DC. I want to emphasize that this is **not** an web application. The task that I have to do is to figure out how to establish a database connection in Adobe Acrobat and then save all the form data to the database. Currently, it is an Access database. I tried the ADBC methods of getDatabaseSource function and it says that ADBC is not defined. Can anyone clarify how I would be able to establish a database connection in Adobe Acrobat DC? I would also like to know if Adobe Acrobat can do read and write into the database.

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Comment: ADBC has been dropped several versions ago. Just so, the best workaround coming to my mind would be an automatization solution with a file interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

ADBC is not supported in Acrobat DC and references to it were removed from the Acrobat DC SDK. See link to the documentation below.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJSChanges%2FADBC_Support_Removed_from_Documentation.htm&rhsearch=ADBC&rhhlterm=ADBC&rhsyns=%20